# Convert all rows of a column into comma separated values

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a table with this structure in Sql server 2005.

```
TABLE TPilot
(
    Num_Office char(3) NULL,
    AppID char(3) NULL
)
```

and having around 998 records in the table with "Num_Office" value starting from 2 to 999.
I want to get all office values in a single row with comma separated values like 2,3,4,5..999

The below is the query which i using right now-

```
select stuff((select ','+ Num_Office from TPilot for xml path('')),1,1,'')
```

The issue here is-it does not return all the row values. it just return around 65 rows.

```
2  ,3  ,4  ,5  ,6  ,7  ,8  ,9  ,10 ,11 ,12 ,13 ,14 ,15 ,16 ,17 ,18 ,19 ,20 ,21 ,22 ,23 ,24 ,25 ,26 ,27 ,28 ,29 ,30 ,31 ,32 ,33 ,34 ,35 ,36 ,37 ,38 ,39 ,40 ,41 ,42 ,43 ,44 ,45 ,46 ,47 ,48 ,49 ,50 ,51 ,52 ,53 ,54 ,55 ,56 ,57 ,58 ,59 ,60 ,61 ,62 ,63 ,64 ,65 ,
```

Please suggest what i am missing here.

Comment: This is a display issue with your SSMS - it's cutting off at 250 characters

Comment: Thank you so much. That really helped otherwise i was really puzzled what's going on. When i executed same query in a storedproc outside of SSMS then i can see entire string. By the way is there any setting avaliable in SSMS by which i can disable this cutting off 250 characters?

Comment: Yes, it should be in tools-options-query results.  Check both grid and text output, but there are setting limiting what you can return

Answer (score 0):

**THIS SHOULD SOLVE YOUR PROBLEM.**

```
create table #Num_Office (Num_Office char(3),APPID CHAR(3))

insert into #Num_Office (Num_Office,APPID) values ('1',1)
insert into #Num_Office (Num_Office,APPID) values ('2',1)
insert into #Num_Office (Num_Office,APPID) values ('3',1)
-- ADD YOUR ROWS AS PER NEED ...

declare @tmp varchar(250)
SET @tmp = ''
select @tmp = @tmp + Num_Office + ', ' from #Num_Office

select SUBSTRING(@tmp, 0, LEN(@tmp))

DROP TABLE #Num_Office
```